# While Animating windows forms to slide in, Form Appearing at wrong location

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, animation, location

I have datagridviews on windows form, i am adding records to datagridview using small add dialogs, i want them to animate in, when the user presses the button on which they are loaded. I am using

```
 [DllImport("user32")]
        static extern bool AnimateWindow(IntPtr hwnd, int time, int flags);
```

> Source: http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/kirtan007/761/

The Dialogs are animating in but at the top left of the screen. I am using belowcode on the Load event of the add dialog:

```
//Set the Location  negative values are being returned when my dialog appears
                this.Location = new Point(LocationMainX + WidthOfMain, locationMainy + 10);

                //Animate form
                AnimateWindow(this.Handle, 750, AW_SLIDE | AW_HOR_POSITIVE);
```

In the Parent form i am passing its location to child add form

```
AddForm form = new AddForm (this.DesktopLocation)
form.ShowDialog(); //I have also noticed doing form.Show(); messes with the position of dialog
```

My Main Form loads within another form so I am guessing it is returning relative location. But i tried:

```
AddForm form = new AddForm (this.Parent.DesktopLocation)
    form.ShowDialog();
```

this doesnt return negative values but returns (0,24) which is also incorrect. as dialog is animating about 150 pixels above parent form.

**when i set the form relative too this.Parent.Parent.Location then it appears right,** so i guess is there any formal way of accessing the root parent of an application rather than doing this.parent.parent.....

Comment: Can you be more specific about the form being "at the wrong location". Is it too high or low, too far left or right or random. Where should it be?

Comment: i have updated the question, " top left of the screen"

Comment: Are the numbers you supply relative to the parent window? Just take off the `LocationMainX` and `locationMainy` perhaps?

Comment: Set the StartPosition property of the form to Manual.

Comment: @HansPassant did do that again the position is (0,24) 150 pixels above parent form. while it should be this.Parent.DesktopLocation

Comment: @ChrisF if i take it off how would i place the form in the custom position i want

Comment: You misunderstand. Take off just the `Location` values. Leave the `Width` and `Height` values. If the numbers are already relative to the parent form they'll be offset even further by including the location.

Comment: @ChrisF, when i set the form relative too this.Parent.Parent.Location then it appears right, but this could easily crash when the design changes again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per your edit, you can just use `this.ParentForm` instead of `this.Parent`.  Check for null, just in case, etc.

**Update:**

Not really sure where you want this form to show up.  Maybe just use some [pinvoke](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/user32.getwindowrect):

```
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

[DllImport("user32.dll")]
[return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.Bool)]
static extern bool GetWindowRect(HandleRef hWnd, out RECT lpRect);

[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
public struct RECT
{
  public int Left;
  public int Top;
  public int Right;
  public int Bottom;
}
```

And then to show the form:

```
RECT fromRECT;
GetWindowRect(new HandleRef(this, button1.Handle), out fromRECT);
form.Location = new Point(fromRECT.Left + (fromRECT.Right - fromRECT.Left), fromRECT.Top);
form.Show();
```

The form will show up to the right of the button.

Comment: this does solve immediate problem, but objective of placing the new form in a specific location is still not solved as i wanted to place the new form relative to a button in the parent form. and this button is nested in multiple control like splitter panel and group box. it would be great if can find the location of that button relative to main form and not the control in which it exists

Comment: @jaminator Updated.  Just to double-check, is this an MDI application?